# convertir este query a una consulta con query builder de laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Necesito realizar esta consulta que me funciona perfectamente en mariadb pero no encuentro como hacerla con el query builder de laravel 
esta es la consulta sql:

```
SELECT productos_id,precio_compra, sum(cantidad) as

cantidad,COUNT(precio_compra) FROM `detalle_compras` WHERE 

DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%01 %2019') GROUP BY precio_compra
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$detalle = DB::table('detalle_compras')
        ->select(
           DB::raw("productos_id,precio_compra, sum(cantidad) as 
              cantidad,COUNT(precio_compra)") 
        )
->where("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%01 %2019')")->orderBy('precio_compra')
->get();
```